# Illustrator Offset multiple paths and discard original

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I have a file with a large amount of small objects.  I want to inset their outlines to make them smaller and discard the original paths.  I do not want to use outline stroke or have any extra paths that are visible or not.  Is there a way of doing this without having to go and manually select the original paths to delete them.  Kind of like inset path in InkScape.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly...

Select the objects and choose `Effects > Path > Offset Path` and enter your negative value. ... notice its the **Effects menu** and **not** the Object Menu item.

Note the **Appearance Panel**. The Effect **must** be applied to the `Fill`:

[image]

This won't work if it's applied anywhere else in the Appearance stack. If your object have "Mixed Appearance" you may need to use `Select Same` to target those with similar fills first and apply the effect.

Once the effect is in place, choose `Object > Expand Appearance` and the offset should be "baked in" without any left over, residual paths.

Answer (score 3):

Using *Offset Path* is perfect for your scenario

- Select all Objects
- Object→Path→Offset Path→( **-** #) <sub>important to be a negative number</sub>
- Now hit <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (to cut the smaller items)
- Select all other items

  - delete
- Paste in *exact* position <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (the *cut* items)

[image]

Comment: Snap: [How do I reduce the thickness of 100+ icons in Adobe Illustrator?](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/70109)

Comment: @Cai I never saw that post, oops.

Answer (score 0):

If you have objects on seperate layers and you want to keep it like that, apply the offset, hit cmd+3 to hide, then marque over the original shapes and delete. Then hit Alt+3 to show the offset paths.